# How do I make Haproxy error out if the instead of going to the next acl

Tags: haproxy, access-control-list

I have the below configuration for haproxy

```
frontend ft_ssl_vip
       bind *:443
     #  bind 10.0.0.10:443
        mode tcp

  tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
  tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }

default_backend bk_ssl_default
#using SNI for routing
backend bk_ssl_default
  mode tcp
        # Define hosts
        acl benlearnscode req_ssl_sni -i benlearnscode.com
        acl apphost2 req_ssl_sni -i apphost2.com

        ## figure out which one to use
       # use_backend benlearnscode if host_benlearnscode
       # use_backend apphost2 if host_apphost2
         use-server server1 if benlearnscode
         use-server server2 if apphost2
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Back end does TCP forwarding to the application server listening on port 443
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
 option ssl-hello-chk
 server server1 18.217.229.105:443
 server server2 216.128.246.130:443
```

if the user goes to benlearnscode.com they go to server 1. If the user goes to apphost2.com they should get server 2. This is working fine if both backend servers are up. However, if one server is down, it will not error out it will just send it to the other server. For example if server 1 is down and the user goes to https://benlearnscode.com, then that user will end up at the apphost 2 backend aka server 2. How can I get it to error out instead of going to the wrong server in that situation?

Answer (score 0):

I've always separated host ACL's at the frontend eg

```
frontend ft_ssl_vip
  bind *:443
  #  bind 10.0.0.10:443
  mode tcp

  tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
  tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }
  # Define hosts
  acl benlearnscode req_ssl_sni -i benlearnscode.com
  acl apphost2 req_ssl_sni -i apphost2.com

  #using SNI for routing
  use_backend Server1 if benlearnscode
  use_backend Server2 if apphost2

  default_backend bk_ssl_default

backend bk_ssl_default
  mode tcp
## Default / catch all

backend Server1
  mode tcp
  option ssl-hello-chk
  server server1 18.217.229.105:443

backend Server2
  mode tcp
  option ssl-hello-chk
  server server2 216.128.246.130:443
```